# How can I change the theme of different posts using a plugin?

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-options

I'd like some posts to look different from others.

Wordpress let's me easily switch themes for pages, but not posts.

Is there a plugin that will let me do that for posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/

Comment: To be clear, this allows you to choose another template file in the same theme. It does not use a different theme for a different post (which would be much harder I believe, because themes are ser up early in the loading process, before posts are queried).

Comment: Ya possible typo by the OP, I'm assuming he is referring to page templates.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for understanding. I meant a different design from within the theme I'm currently using.

Comment: custom post templates ought to be in the WP core

Answer (score 0):

Custom CSS is an excellent plugin:
http://webtoolkit4.me/2010/06/11/wordpress-plugin-custom-css-stylesheet-for-posts-or-pages/